# IE 11 Autocomplete - Not Working

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, internet-explorer-11, autofill

IE11 Autocomplete not showing me any suggestion for name, address, phone number, email etc fields, i filled the same page form fields a number of times. And i checked Autocomplete is ON in IE11 settings and page form fields also have attributes like autocomplete="given-name name", autocomplete="shipping street-address", autocomplete="home tel", autocomplete="home email" etc.

Only thing is, for submitting, form have button type input field calling 'submitFunc' onClick of it, to make sure IE saves the fields for AutoComplete, I'm calling the below function as well

Still it's not resolving the issue.

```
submitFunc: function () {
  this.saveForAutocomplete();
  .....      
},

saveForAutocomplete: function() {
if (window.external && ('AutoCompleteSaveForm' in window.external)) {
    var form = document.getElementById ("step1RegForm");
    window.external.AutoCompleteSaveForm(form);
}
else {
    console.log("Your browser does not support AutoCompleteSaveForm");
   }
}
```

Please suggest any solution to this.

---

EDIT: HTML code https://embed.plnkr.co/qbY9S67AHOj6XGiDYrtM/

Comment: What does your HTML markup look like?

Comment: Have you took a look at the dev console? There's maybe an error message waiting for you. Most likely `this` is not what you think it is, hence it doesn't have the referred method.

Comment: @Nisarg: I added HTML markup

Comment: @Teemu: It's all fine. It's going into if loop, no error in console. Thanks guys for your support.

Comment: @Teemu: I'm using BackBoneJs